# Windows MSI Installer: dependency resolving is not working, wrong assembly is installed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, assembly-binding-redirect

i have a problem with an msi installer in Visual Studio 2019.
Somehow some assemblies will get installed with the wrong version

1. debug folder

   - FileName : **System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll**
   - FileVersion : **4.6.26011.01**
   - AssemblyVersion : **4.2.0.0**
2. install folder

   - FileName : **System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll**
   - FileVersion : **4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1**
   - AssemblyVersion : **4.0.0.0**

All the wrong Assemblys are not directly referenced by nuget.

- System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
- System.IO.Compression.dll
- System.Net.Http.dll
- System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
- System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
- System.Security.SecureString.dll

When i start my app locally from debug or release folder every thing is working as it should.

my binding redirect looks like this:

```
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
...
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

**for example**

file not found exception :

```
 "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, 
 Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

directed from   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.....

Somehow this is strange to me, i do not understand whats going on and why the bindings are failing
Maybe someoan can help me with that or explain me the behaviour

Comment: You use Visual Studio Installer projects or WiX or something else?

Comment: i use the [vs installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) , even tried with [installshield](https://www.flexerasoftware.de/install/products/installshield.html) same problem